# Linq with EF, include specific columns

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

I have two classes:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public bool Hidden { get; set; }
}

public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to select some Categories including Articles, but without Article.Body. Method syntax is more preferred.
Something like:

```
IEnumerable<Category> categories = _context
    .Categories
    .Where(c => c.Hidden == false)
    .Include(c => c.Articles)
    .OrderBy(c => c.Weight);
```

Not sure how to specify which columns exactly to select (eagerly) on the included Articles.

Answer (score 1):

`Include` doesn't allow projections, you can only include complete entities.

But there is a way out.

This is a typical case that you should solve by *table splitting*. By table splitting you "split" a table over two (or more) entities, so it's easier to filter e.g. light data from heavy data or public data from secure data.

In your case the class model (for `Article`) would look like this:

```cs
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual ArticleBody ArticleBody { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleBody
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And the mappings:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Article>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.ArticleBody)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal();

modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().ToTable("Article");
modelBuilder.Entity<ArticleBody>().ToTable("Article");
```

Now if you do...

```cs
_context.Categories
        .Where(c => !c.Hidden)
        .Include(c => c.Articles)
```

...you'll see that only `Article`s without body texts will be selected in the generated SQL.

If you want the body as well, you do

```cs
_context.Categories
        .Where(c => !c.Hidden)
        .Include(c => c.Articles.Select(a => a.ArticleBody))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i did not understand your question, but I think you can specify what columns you want in your select statement.

Simple example:

```
var query = from c in Categories
            select c.Name, c.CategoryId;
```